# Excel lookup query

Tags: excel

I'm not all that with excel and this is driving me nuts. I have a table with 3 columns A B C.

- A has up to 150 names.
- B has their chosen number from 0-9.
- C has 5 random numbers entered from 0-9.

After the numbers have been entered in C, I need to find who in A has a match to the numbers in C and how many times. 
I.E:

```
Bill    7
Mary    4
in C--      2 7 5 4 4
```

Results need to show (could be on another sheet):

```
Bill    1
Mary    2
```

have spent hours googling, but either can't find help, or I'm too stupid to see it.

Comment: Does `C` have the same value for each row?

Comment: No, C has only 5 rows with one number in each, but they may or may not be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COUNTIF` to do that.

You can copy/paste to get the name list to the other sheet first.

Then, use:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!C:C, VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet1!A:B, 2, 0)))
```

Or if you are able to copy both columns A and B into `Sheet2`,

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!C:C, B1)
```

Then copy/paste as values and last delete column B.

---

If it can be done on the same sheet, you can consider:

```
=COUNTIF($C$1:$C$5, B1)
```

Comment: Can't do the copy paste thing, and the numbers in c will be changed about every 4 minutes, so its a constantly updating thing, someone has to copy the results each time they change to other sheets.

Comment: @tonyG_cyprus Okay, what about the first one? You can still use the first one, right?

Comment: Tried that in various cell and columns in sheet 2, but all I get is a single 0 where I need a name and an amount of matches. To clarify,

Comment: @tonyG_cyprus Wait, you mean you cannot copy column A as well? Otherwise, you could perhaps put `=Sheet1!A1` in Sheet2 cell A1. Otherwise, it's not possible to pull data from another sheet just like that...

Comment: it wouldn't let me finish! basically, i'm try ing to help out a mate, and I'm used to sql not excel. Out of my depth...Yes, I'm afraid I am!

Comment: @tonyG_cyprus Okay, it sure would be easier with SQL I believe. I still find it quite strange that no copy/paste is allowed.

Comment: The answers needn't be on another sheet, as long as the answers are copyable to an admin sheet that we have no control over. if I can just get the answers correct I.E Who's won and how many times each game, i'm able to sort out the rest. Formulas fox me in excel!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43908/discussion-between-tonyg-cyprus-and-jerry)